# "EntityType has no key defined", but I added [Key], why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model class like this:

```
public class Task
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskId;

    public string TaskDescription;
    public DateTime StartTime;
    public DateTime FinishTime;
    public  bool isActive;
}
```

and following table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks]
(
    [TaskId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [TaskDescription] NVARCHAR(max) NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] DATE NOT NULL,
    [FinishTime] DATE NOT NULL,
    [isActive] BIT  NOT NULL DEFAULT 1   
)
```

After compilation, I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information:
>
> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Planner.Domain.Concrete.Task: : EntityType 'Task' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. Tasks: EntityType: EntitySet 'Tasks' is based on type 'Task' that has no keys defined.

How to fix that one?

Comment: I wonder weather it possible to change column DATE to "time(7)" column type without changing model's DATETIME field. if it is not possible, what is corresponding c# type for time(7)?

Answer (score 8):

please add get and set accessors.Like so.

```
    [Key]
    public int TaskId {get; set;}
    public string TaskDescription {get; set;}
    public DateTime StartTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime FinishTime {get; set;}
    public  bool isActive {get; set;}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `[Key]` for `TaskId`

Comment: @Rob: by **convention**, a column called `Id` or `(tablename)Id` will be **automatically** used as key. Since the table/entity is `Task`, `TaskId` will automatically be used as the key

Comment: @Rob due to Entity Framework Conventions, the `[Key]` should be inferred correctly by the context here.

Comment: @marc_s Claies Never knew that! That's pretty cool, thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: do you know what is suitable model's data type for "time(7)" database type ? thanks